# Transform scale keeps the original space around the scaled element

Tags: html, css

I have two nested divs. The `inner one` is `transform: scale(0.5)`.

Both are `display: inline-block;`.

What I need to happen is the `outer div` fits it's width to the width of the inner one. That's what I supposed to happen but not. What occur is that the outer div «thinks» the inner div has it's original size.

The outer div fits it's width to the inner's width only if the inner div is `transform: scale(1)` but not using an scale factor less than 1, for example: `0.5` (see example).

I need some way to achieve this by CSS in an elegant way.

```css
.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.green {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

.box_1,
.box_2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box_1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_2 green">
  <div class="box_1 red">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A brutal way would be to virtually reduce space needed by element.

Your example shows a known width & height, so it makes it easy. else you would need a javascript method.

```
.box_1 {
    width:  300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: left top;
  margin-bottom:-150px;
  margin-right:-150px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0bc4sxk3/1/

Scaling up would mean positive margins.

Transform only happens at screen, elements still use initial room and place  needed in the flow of the document.

Comment: that way doesn't work for me because I need the outer div fit's it's size to the inner one. In other words: both have the same size.

Comment: @nightclub  if you  set same size to both of them, there is no way that parent will shrink. Your fiddle was missing this :( I guess you misunderstand how transform works

Comment: I didn't specified any size to the outer div, so I expected the outer div could shrink

Comment: @nightclub it won't, as i wrote at the end of my answer. position:relative; + coordonates does the same it only moves element at screen, not in the layout ;)  https://jsfiddle.net/0bc4sxk3/3/ similar problem to what you are facing with transform. it is the normal behavior :)

Answer (score 12):

I think that one solution is to wrap the scaled-down element into an element with `overflow: hidden`.
The wrapper should have the exact dimensions of the scaled-down content.

This solution was best for me.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.box_1,
.box_2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.green {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_2 green">
  <div class="box_1 red">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! However, I think `position: absolute` isn't needed.

Comment: I converted your solution to a snippet demo, using the original HTML and styling. Does it work as expected? Please revise as needed to demonstrate.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead

Comment: Good solution! I had the exact same problem and overflow: hidden; did the job for me

Answer (score 3):

Coming late to the party, but another way is to use a sizing element that is empty, not scaled, has the same external size as the scaled down element and sits underneath the scaled element. This drives the sizing of the parent, and the scaled element is then positioned absolutely on top of the sizing element.

```css
.red { background-color: #f00; }
.green { background-color: #0f0; }
.blue { background-color: #00f; }

.container {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.sizingBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 transform: scale(0.5);
 transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container green">
      <div class="sizingBox blue"></div>
     <div class="content red">Hello World</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for a copy-pasta React Componet, this seems to work based on Guy's code:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props
  extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement> {
  scale?: number;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  fullHeight: number;
  fullWidth: number;
}

export const ScaleBox: React.FC<Props> = ({
  scale = 1,
  style,
  fullWidth,
  fullHeight,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      data-comment={"ScaleBox Container"}
      style={{ position: "relative", display: "inline-block", ...style }}
      {...rest}
    >
      <div
        data-comment={"ScaleBox Sizing Box"}
        style={{ width: fullWidth * scale, height: fullHeight * scale }}
      ></div>
      <div
        data-comment={"ScaleBox Content"}
        style={{
          transform: `scale(${scale})`,
          transformOrigin: "top left",
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: React isn't tagged on the question. This answer is far out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Even later, I've built on mikeysee's React component and written one that works with content that sizes dynamically (it uses negative margins to avoid resizing the children's content):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import useResizeObserver from '@react-hook/resize-observer';

interface Props
    extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
        React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,
        HTMLDivElement
    > {
    scale?: number;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
}

/**
 * The ScaleBox is an element that scales its content using CSS transform scale
 * and makes sure the flow around the box is as if the box had the size
 * according to the applied scale.
 *
 * The parent element of a ScaleBox must have the overflow: 'hidden' style.
 */
export const ScaleBox: React.FC<Props> = ({ scale = 1, style, children }) => {
    const [marginX, setMarginX] = React.useState('0px');
    const [marginY, setMarginY] = React.useState('0px');
    const divRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useResizeObserver(divRef, (target) => {
        setMarginX(`${(scale - 1) * target.contentRect.width}px`);
        setMarginY(`${(scale - 1) * target.contentRect.height}px`);
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (divRef.current) {
            setMarginX(`${(scale - 1) * divRef.current.offsetWidth}px`);
            setMarginY(`${(scale - 1) * divRef.current.offsetHeight}px`);
        }
    }, [scale]);

    return (
        <div
            ref={divRef}
            style={{
                ...style,
                transform: `scale(${scale})`,
                transformOrigin: 'top left',
                marginRight: marginX,
                marginBottom: marginY
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: React isn't tagged on the question. This answer is far out of scope.