# Transform scale with iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, scale

I have an iframe, I make it small using scale, the size of iframe is changed, but the body of the page is as big, as iframe was (vertical scrollbar). Am I doing something wrong?

```css
.frame {
      width: 1777px;
      height: 2000px;
      transform: scale(0.05);
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe class="frame" src="https://wikipedia.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Transform scale does not alter the space allocated. If you lower the actual height and width then the element will take up the smaller space.

Comment: @AHaworth that's the problem, I need to change the size of iframe, without changing actual size, otherwise it will trigger media queries. Any ideas, how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the iframe into a container - the container having the small dimensions - and position the iframe absolute then it seems to work OK (i.e. the iframe is kidded that it has the large viewport dimensions).

```css
.container {
  width: calc(1777px * 0.05);
  height: calc(2000px * 0.05);
  position: relative;
}

.frame {
  width: 1777px;
  height: 2000px;
  transform: scale(0.05);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe class="frame" src="https://wikipedia.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also found similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276988/6723047

Answer (score 0):

```
.frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 100vh was probably bad example (changed it). I want iframe to be that exact size: 1777x2000